# RestAPI post call setters and getters Issue

Tags: java, arrays, string, rest, getter-setter

I need to send the payload and below are the details. I'm not sure if the error is due to passing empty array or what reason. Please help. Thanks in advance. PS: Due to security, I had to enter the code manually.

```
SumAll sa = new SumAll();
sa.setAge(68);
int[] myTrueAge ={};
sa.setTrueAge(myTrueAge);
```

```
During req it should go as -> "TrueAge":[],)
```

```
SumAll gsa = given().header(----).body(sa).expect().defaultParser(Parser.JSON).when().post(----).as(sumAll.class)
```

**Pojo class:**

```
public class SumAll{
private int Age;
private int[] TrueAge= {};

public int[] getTrueAge(){
return TrueAge;

public void setTrueAge(int[] TrueAge)
TrueAge = TrueAge;
}}
```

**Error:**

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognised field "Allocation" (class pojo.SumAll), not marked as ignorable (14 known properties: ..…........ All properties are mentioned here.....
At [source : (String) " response is given here"
```

Comment: There are at least two syntax errors in the code presented. Please make sure that this is the actual code producing the error. Also, please format the code properly and follow java naming conventions for getters and setters (`gettrueAge()` -> `getTrueAge()`, `settrueAge(...)` -> `setTrueAge(...)`). Jackson might rely on those exact getters and setters.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I have manually entered the code as I can't use work PC. In real application, I have given correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You have two ways to ignore unknown fields from Json in your POJO

**By using annotation**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
    
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class SumAll {

}
```

**Or deserialise by pre-configured ObjectMapper**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
    
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
mapper.readValue(json, SumAll.class);
```